# How to get type of object when using ole automation (C++)

Tags: vba, visual-c++, com, ole

I'm using the autowrap function to interact with VBA and now I get the control using item method as below.

```
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);
VARIANT x;
x.vt = VT_INT;
x.intVal = index;
wchar_t method[] =  L"Item";
hr = AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, pControls, method,1,x);
pObject = result.pdispVal;
```

I can get the name of the control item using this code below:

```
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);
wchar_t method[] =  L"Name";
hr = AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pObject, method, 0);
QString name=QString::fromWCharArray(result.bstrVal);
```

But I can't seem to find a property to get the type of object (textbox, commandbutton and etc). In VBA, there is a TypeName() function to get the type. So how can I actually do it in OLE automation autowrap function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example... could be optimized with a function to check the result and throw/catch an exception, but it is what it is.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
   class CComInit
   {
      public:
      CComInit()
      {
         CoInitialize(NULL);
      }

      ~CComInit()
      {
         CoUninitialize();
      }
   } _init;


   IDispatchPtr lpDisp;
   HRESULT hr = lpDisp.CreateInstance(L"Scripting.FileSystemObject");

   if (FAILED(hr))
   {
      _com_error err(hr);

      printf("Error %s\n", err.ErrorMessage());
      return 0;
   }

   ITypeInfoPtr lpTypeInfo;
   hr = lpDisp->GetTypeInfo(0, 0, &lpTypeInfo);
   if (FAILED(hr))
   {
      _com_error err(hr);
      printf("Error %s\n", err.ErrorMessage());
      return 0;
   }

   CComBSTR ccbName, ccbDocString;
   hr = lpTypeInfo->GetDocumentation(-1, &ccbName, &ccbDocString, NULL, NULL)   ;
   if (FAILED(hr))
   {
      _com_error err(hr);
      printf("Error %s\n", err.ErrorMessage());
      return 0;
   }

   printf("Type name: %S\n", ccbName.m_str);
   printf("Doc: %S\n", ccbDocString.m_str);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I just found out that I can use things like QAxObject to interact with excel, which can go around this problem.